# How can I use importScripts() in a Service Worker when using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox-webpack-plugin

In a Service Worker, I'm trying to import another helper script using importScripts, however I keep getting a `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:5000/src/js/utility.js' failed to load.`

I have the following code in the Service Worker:

```js
importScripts('../src/js/utility.js');

workbox.routing.registerRoute(/.*(?:jsonplaceholder\.typicode)\.com.*$/, function(args){
    console.log('Json placeholder being called');
    // Send request to the server.
    return fetch(args.event.request)
        .then(function(res){
            // Clone the response obtained from the server.
            var clonedRes = res.clone();
            // Clear data stored in the posts store.
            clearAllData('posts') // Function from helper file
                .then(function(){
                    return clonedRes.json()
                })
                .then(function(data){
                    for(var key in data){
                        // Write the updated data to the posts store.
                        writeData('posts', data[key]) // Function from helper file
                    }
                });

            return res;
        })
});

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest);
```

And in `utility.js` I have the following code:

```js
import { openDB } from 'idb';

export function writeData(st, data){
    console.log(st, data);
}

export function clearAllData(st){
    console.log(st);
}
```

The functions don't do anything yet, but even these placeholder ones don't work! Eventually I'd like to be able to use the `idb` npm module, so that's why I'm doing this in a helper, so I can also use it from my normal Javascript file.

Also I'm using Webpack to build my files, and in another project where I don't use it, it works fine, however in this one it just doesn't find the file after building, so I'm thinking Webpack may be screwing something up.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the error message very carefully, you see what the problem is :)

Your Service Worker script tries to import "/src/js/utility.js" but it is *NOT* available. If you open your browser and go to that address, can you see the file? I'm fairly sure you cannot :)

When you build the application with webpack it most likely puts all your files to a directory called "dist". Your Service Worker is *ONLY* able to import those files. Think about it: when you deploy the application somewhere, only the files in dist/ will be on the server, not the files in src/, right? For this reason the SW script is not able to import the file you want it to import.

Sadly I'm not a webpack expert so I'm not sure how to tell webpack to bundle the file for you and include it in your Service Worker script file :-/

Comment: If this is the case, you will get another error stating the response code (404). If you don't see such a message, it means that the script is available but the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 3):

Found out that to import script files, I have to copy them to the dist folder as they are, otherwise they won't be usable by the Service Worker.
As such, I modified the `vue.config.js` file to include the following (after `module.exports`):

```js
chainWebpack: config => {
        config
            .plugin('copy')
            .tap(args => {
                args[0].push({
                    from: 'project-location\\src\\js', 
                    to: 'project-location\\dist'});
                return args;
            })
    },
```

This will copy the files in `src/js` to the `dist` folder, and then we can import them in the Service Worker file with this line at the top of the file:

`importScripts('utility.js');`

I haven't however been able to find a way to import npm modules, so I had to replace the `idb` module with another `idb.js` file, that is imported in the `utility.js` file with a similar line of code:

`importScripts('idb.js');`

Both `utility.js` and `idb.js` are located under `src/js`.

So not a perfect solution, but it works. Thanks to `pate` for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: This seems to work, but as I have multiple file referencing each other, this solution fails, only works for a single file

Answer (score 2):

Here , workaround :

1. serve the javascript from your server
2. import the script with `self.importScripts()` of the workers Api , see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts.

Links:

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/09/fresher-sw
- https://web.dev/module-workers/

Answer (score 0):

I use the CopyWebpackPlugin to solve this issue. It lets you copy the files, and replace content. So after copying I remove all the "export " statements from my files, which allows me to keep only one version.

```js
new CopyWebpackPlugin ([{
  from: 'src/js/mylist.js',
  to: '',
  transform(content) {
    return content.toString().replace(/export /g, '');
  },
}])
```

npm install -D copy-webpack-plugin to install it